# Is there a wordpress slider that supports partial view?

Tags: wordpress, slider

I'm looking for a Wordpress slider that supports partial view and mouse drag? Or a way to accomplish it with known sliders like Revolution slider. Here's an example of what I mean: https://nerds.company/

[image: This is what I'm looking for]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any that supports it out of the box and because the code they generate is usually made of hundreds of embedded divs entangled in poorly documented CSS/JS, there is not much you can customize yourself either.

You would be better of starting with a clean slider framework such as slickslider or splide and work from there.